# How to perform a table join on two DFS tables and update the left table based on its result?

Tags: join, updates, dolphindb, distributed-database

Two DFS tables, `pt` and `pt1`,  with the same schema were created in the database `dfs://db` using the following scripts.

```
n=10000
ID=rand(100, n)
dates=2022.08.07..2022.08.11
date=rand(dates, n)
vol=rand(1..10 join int(), n)
t=table(ID, date, vol)

if(existsDatabase("dfs://db1")){
  dropDatabase("dfs://db1")
}
db=database(directory="dfs://db1", partitionType=RANGE, partitionScheme=0 50 100)
pt=db.createPartitionedTable(table=t, tableName=`pt, partitionColumns=`ID)
pt.append!(t)
pt1=db.createPartitionedTable(table=t, tableName=`pt1, partitionColumns=`ID)
pt1.append!(t)
```

I want to update the left table (table `pt1`) after performing a left semi-join on `pt1` and `pt`.

I tried the following two methods:

```
update pt1 set date = pt_date from lsj(pt1, pt, `ID)

x = select * from lsj(pt1, pt, `ID)
update pt1 set date = x.pt_date from x
```

But both ways failed and raised the errors as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your update issue cannot be solved. You can get it cracked using the first method after the release of version 1.30.21/2.00.9.

In addition, the second error thrown did not exactly explain the problem. The error is reported when updating each partition. We will improve this error message in the subsequent versions.